# How to convert QPointf to Point in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

- I have some list of points ,which i have stored  in `QList<QPointF>`
- But now i want to convert that **QPointF** into **Point** in opencv.
  How can i do that.

Comment: have you done some research first? take a look at [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv::Point` is simply a typedef of `cv::Point2i`, aka `Point_<int>`.

In practice, you can simply covert from `QPointF` like:

```
QList<QPointF> list;

// loop over i 
const QPointF& qt_p = list[i];
cv::Point cv_p(qt_p.x(), qt_p.y());
```

Please note that the coordinates will be truncated from `float` to `int`.

Comment: @Miki-Do you know how to crop part of a image which is enclosed by some points?.Means i have some points around eye and i want to crop that eye part.So how can i do it.

Comment: This can be easily done with: 1) `fillConvexPoly` to get the binary mask, 2) `boundingRect` to get the bounding box of your points, and 3) `copyTo` to copy on a new image only the masked part of the original image. If you need further details you can ask a new question, since an answer to a different question is not suited to the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

`QPointF` holds the `x` and `y` valued as `double`s by default, and openCV's `Point_` is a template, so:

```
Point_<double> convert(const QPointF & pt)
{
    return Point_<double>(pt.x(), pt.y());
}
```

Comment: i want to draw line between these points.and for that i need to convert them from QPointF to Point.